# Is this $\epsilon-\delta-$proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity

I have to Show that

$$\mathbb{C} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}; z \rightarrow \Re  z$$

is a continuous function using the $\epsilon-\delta-$criteria.

So what I did is the following:

I have to Show that there is a $\delta$ with $|z - z_0| < \delta$ so that $\Re z- \Re z_0|<\epsilon $. With $z = a + ib$ and $z_0 = a_0 + ib_0$ that would be showing $|a-a_0 + i(b-b_0)| < \delta$ and $|a-a_0|<\epsilon$

Now because of

$$|a-a_0 + i(b-b_0)|<\delta$$

we have also

$$|a-a_0| < \delta$$

So we choose $\delta = \epsilon$ and have: $|a-a_0 + i(b-b_0)|<\delta \rightarrow |a-a_0| < \delta = \epsilon$

This seems pretty right to me but I just wanted to be sure - can you please check that? Especially if that is technically acceptable:)

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your mapping precisely? Is the function $z \mapsto e \cdot z$ or $z\mapsto e^z$ or $z \mapsto \text{ Re }z$?

Comment: Oh it should mean $Re z$ here - uhm sorry .. I will try to make it more clear

Comment: Use `\text{}` instead of `mathbb{}`

Comment: Thanks for advice - I used \Re - Looks creepy but works I suppose

Comment: you can also use `\operatorname{Re}` i.e. $\operatorname{Re}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The triangle $(0,\Re z,\mathrm i\cdot\Im z)$ is right-angled at $0$ hence Pythagoras taught us that the square of the hypotenuse $|z|$ is the sum of the squares of the sides $|\Re z|$ and $|\Im z|$.

Thus, $|z|^2=|\Re z|^2+|\Im z|^2\geqslant|\Re z|^2$. Likewise $|\Re z-\Re w|\leqslant|z-w|$ for every $z$ and $w$. To sum up, for every $\varepsilon$, $\delta=\varepsilon$ fits the definition of the continuity of the function $\Re:z\mapsto\Re z$.

Comment: Wow.. thats one clean answer! Nice! Thank you for that - both of you I suppose :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to show that a function which assignes To each complex number its real part is continuous. Your proof is true.it's enough to get $\delta\leq\epsilon$.

Comment: Ah yes - that is exactly what I am asked to show. I am just curious - is there a different Notation for that in the "english-speaking" maths?